# Firebase Realtime Database - how to store data from multiple activities under the same child element?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android application I use Firebase Realtime Database and Android Studio. I can store data of one activity of the application. But, how can I store data from multiple activities under the same child element ? I really need help. I have seen similar questions on this forum but no answers have helped me yet. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder how to add multiple child nodes with an automatic ID to a node, you're looking for [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

If you're currently doing this to set a value:

```
ref.setValue(value);
```

Then you can make a list under `ref` by using:

```
ref.push().setValue(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I just made one class to store all data of all activities at the same time and it works.